# Component for processing cube

Tags: c#, ssas

how do we process a cube or access OLAP database through ASP.Net with C# code? what is the component to be used, in C#.Net for connecting  OLAP database or process actions in anaysis Services ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For processing, use Microsoft.AnalysisServices library, example code looks like:

```
    Server server = new Server();
    server.Connect(cubeConnectionString);

    Database database = server.Databases.FindByName(databaseName);
    Cube cube = database.Cubes.FindByName(cubeName);

    cube.Process(ProcessType.ProcessFull);
```

For querying, use Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient library, example code looks like:

```
    using (Adomd.AdomdConnection adomdConnection = new Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection())
    {
        adomdConnection.ConnectionString = cubeConnectionString;
        Adomd.AdomdCommand adomdCommand = new Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdCommand();
        adomdCommand.Connection = adomdConnection;
        adomdCommand.CommandText = mdxQuery;
        adomdConnection.Open();
        cellSet = adomdCommand.ExecuteCellSet();
        adomdConnection.Close();
    }
```

Note that the two namespaces overlap, so you may need to alias if you use them in the same place.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms124924(v=SQL.90).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123483(v=SQL.90).aspx

Comment: I dont think you need adomdConnection.Close(); since you use a using statement. However i think you should adomdCommand.Dispose(); since the adomdCommand isnt in the using statement but im not really sure.

Comment: @Meff , Whats the exactly library your "Server" variable is using?

Answer (score 1):

You must process the database, not the cube. Because the cube has only the measures not the dimensions inside. This can give some conflicts.

To Prozess all, Cubes and Dimensions you must process the whole database:

```
Server server = new Server();
server.Connect(cubeConnectionString);

Database database = server.Databases.FindByName(databaseName);

database.Process(ProcessType.ProcessFull);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer for this already shared above but just sharing that I too had used the same Microsoft.AnalysisServices by API referring the sample project downloaded from [my blog post](http://www.iminfo.in/post/process-ssas-cube-in-c-sharp-programmatically-using-microsoft-analysisservices-dll) to process cube from C# but **when the dimension data gets changed then you need to process the database rather cube**.

Also you can use EffectiveUserName property of connection string when an end user identity must be impersonated on the server.

**NOTE:** To use EffectiveUserName property, the caller must have administrative permissions in Analysis Services.

Answer (score -2):

This example was done with Visual Studio Express 2012 and $44 copy of Ms SQL 2012 (God bless Microsoft for providing so much functionality for so little money).  The OS was Win 8 pro.

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 //the next 2 using's had to be downloaded and "Add Reference"d for Visual Studio Express 2012
 using Microsoft.AnalysisServices;
 using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using System;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 namespace SSASDataview
 {
         partial class Form1
   {
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
    private void RunSSAS(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //i don't think  Dataset is in the Analysis Services directives
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        // provider is the constant olap.  datasource is the same server name you provide for Mgmt Studio or localhost
        // initial catalog is tricky and important.  It is not a standard ms sql database you see in Management Studio,
        // even if your cube was create with tables from a particular database.
        // the only place I was able to see "initial catalog" value was a File -> Open -> Analysis Services Database in 2012 Management Studio
        // it was also the name of the VS2010 solution I used to create the cube.
        AdomdConnection myconnect = new AdomdConnection(@"provider=olap;initial catalog=GLCubeThree;datasource=localhost");
        AdomdDataAdapter mycommand = new AdomdDataAdapter();
        mycommand.SelectCommand = new AdomdCommand();
        mycommand.SelectCommand.Connection = myconnect;
        // this query was created by the "Browser" you see for an Analysis Services project 
        // if you poke around the icons on the browser table the Design Mode icon will give you the cube query
        // I think it's an MDX query, threre are also xml queries you can run with adomd
        mycommand.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Per Balance] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { ([Gltime].[Fisc Per].[Fisc Per].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Gltime].[Fisc Per].&[201301], [Gltime].[Fisc Per].&[201302], [Gltime].[Fisc Per].&[201307] } ) ON COLUMNS FROM [GL Cube]) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS";
        myconnect.Open();
        mycommand.Fill(ds, "tbl");
        myconnect.Close();
        // the below assigns the results of the cube query to a dataGridView
        // if you drag a dataGridView control to your pallete it will create exactly
        // what you need for the line below to work.
        // your project type has to be a Window Forms Applications
        // this code shown here is in the default Form1.Designer.cs not Form1.cs
        dataGridView1.DataSource = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);


    }
    private void Quit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button runssas;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button quit;
}
```

}

Comment: Is there a newer version of ADOMD.NET? The only thing I can found is [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23089) but this was uploaded on 2005

Comment: there is nothing about cube processing here.